# jquery 1.6.2 and IE8 error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In the uncompressed version of jquery 1.6.2 IE8 developer tools is telling me that line 6096 is throwing an error: Object required.

6096 reads: `elem = div.childnodes;`

It is part of an extend -

```
jquery.extend({ 
    clone: function( elem, dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents) {
```

I am basically inserting or editing records in a MySQL db and displaying the records in tabular format. Where my script is breaking is where I am trying to display the HTML code - I initially was using `$(div).html(code)` but then reading a similar problem on here switched to`$(div).empty() $(div).append(code)` but either way I got the same error. Relevant portion of my code is below.

```
 ...

 //building table body
        tableCode += "<tr row=\"row_" + i + "\">";

        tableCode += "<td class=\"fileTitle tableCell\" key=\"title\" " + backgroundColor + "><p class=\"fileTitleTD\">" + fileLink + "</p><p class=\"fileTitleDesc\">" +  dataObj[thisRowData]['fileDescription'] + "</td>";
        tableCode += "<td class=\"fileType tableCell\" key=\"fileType\" " + backgroundColor + ">" + thisFileImage + "&nbsp;" + dataObj[thisRowData]['fileTypeExt'] + "</td>";
        tableCode += "<td class=\"lastUpdate tableCell\" key=\"lastUpdate\" " + backgroundColor + ">" + dataObj[thisRowData]['fileModed'] + "</td>";

        if(thisView == "admin") { 
            tableCode += "<td class=\"edit tableCell\"" + backgroundColor + " key=\"edit\"><p class=\"adminBtns\"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"editRecord\" recordID=\"" + dataObj[thisRowData]['fileId'] + "\">Edit</a></p></td>";
            tableCode += "<td class=\"delete tableCell\"" + backgroundColor + " key=\"delete\"><p class=\"adminBtns\"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"deleteRecord\" recordID=\"" + dataObj[thisRowData]['fileId'] + "\">Delete</a></p></td>";
        }

        tableCode += "</tr>";

    }

    tableCode += "</tbody></table>";

//-->BREAKS HERE
    $("#dataResultsTableBody").empty();
    $("#dataResultsTableBody").append(tableCode);

    //check if dataContainer is being displayed, if not display it
    $("#adminLogInFormContainer").hide();
    $("#siteCategorySelect").show();
    $("#siteCategoryItemTable").show();
```

...

Works fine in current version of Firefox and Safari and the new records or edited versions show when I reload the page. This was also a problem with jquery 1.4.2, I just updated today to see if the latest build fixed the issue. Any ideas if this is a problem on my end or IE's or jquery's? Thanks.

Comment: Does your generated table have `<tbody>` elements?

Comment: Doh! Thanks Pekka, that was it. Got lost in the code there. I'm writing to the <tbody> to the added </tbody></table> was crashing my script in IE. Good eye!

Comment: Ah, okay! Although it was a half guess :) I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: You deserve the points for me not paying attention. : D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `<tbody>` elements in dynamically generated tables. You seem to be missing an opening  tag for that.